# Is "Au jour d'hui" one, two, or three words?

Tags: locutions

Aujour d'hui seems to be a puzzle. Is there a space between Au and jour, or not? Or is it all one word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a single word written ***aujourd'hui***. A case of [univerbation](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Univerbation).

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: C'est marrant cette fatalité des locutions adverbiales de temps. *au par avant - dores en avant...* Avec *aujourd'hui* c'est encore plus marrant puisque cette univerbation est comme à deux étages. (*hui* étant lui même issu de l'univerbation de *ho die*). Curieux tout de même, à ce compte-là, je ne comprends pas bien comment l'apostrophe a fait pour se maintenir. Elle a bien sauté dans *dorénavant*...

Comment: @aCOSwt Peut-être verrons-nous un jour apparaître ***aujourdaujourdhui*** ;-)

Comment: Ha oui, forcément... et avec lui, par conséquence : ***apartirdedorénavant***. ;-)